# MS Graph put on uploadUrl created from createUploadSession results in a 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

When doing a resumable upload to a file that was shared the url returned from createUploadSession can not be used.

Uploading directly with /content works but has a limit of 4MB

Scenario `UserA` shares a file with edit permissions to `UserB`
Using the ms graph javascript sdk

```js
const { uploadUrl } = await this.client.api(`/drives/${driveId}/items/${id}/createUploadSession`).post({});
```

trying to use `uploadUrl` results in a 404 `{"error":{"code":"itemNotFound","message":"The resource could not be found."}}`

Interestingly the `uploadUrl` looks something like this 
`https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{UserA}_{tenant}_com/_api/v2.0/drives/${driveId}/items/${id}/uploadSession?guid='5b85df9e-b524-4000-9883-8106a13e592f'...`

Not sure if its related to UserA being embedded in the url or not.

If `UserA` accesses the same file and does a similar upload everything works fine on the file.

All of the following requests work fine for either User:

```js
await this.client.api(`/drives/${driveId}/items/${id}/checkout`).post({});
await this.client.api(`/drives/${driveId}/items/${id}/content`).putStream(fs.createReadStream(filePath));
await this.client.api(`/drives/${driveId}/items/${id}/checkin`).post({});
```

`uploadUrl` returned from createUploadSession should be valid for any user that had access to create an upload session.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload/replace files shared from another user's OneDrive. Creating an upload session creates a temporary file in the Drive for writing each chunk. Since User B doesn't have read/write access to User A's OneDrive, they cannot create that temporary file (thus the `404 - Not Found`).

Comment: This doesn’t logically make sense to me, if I am sharing a file with read/write access why can’t I make changes to the file?  

Why am I able to upload directly to the file outside of an upload session?   

I am trying to create a custom file handler for my file type I want to offer the same experience as office products from the sounds of it I can if the file is under 4mb since an upload session is not required, but for files larger this isn’t supported?

What are the possible work arounds ? Can I write a temporary file to /me and then copy the file overtop the other?

Comment: This sounds more like a shortcoming with how uploadsession were implemented, that have leaked into incorrect API behavior. I don't see this specifically being documented as a restriction of upload sessions

Comment: Since I don't own those APIs, I can't really speak to how they were implemented or why. I can only speak to my understanding of the existing behavior.